# Javascript - prompt input on div element

Tags: javascript

I would like to instantly print the user input from a prompt in a loop on a div element of id=results .
However, the prompt runs 6 times continuously and then all the inputs are printed in the div.
I want each input to be printed on div one at a time after each prompt input.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  var x = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number"));
  h1 = document.createElement('h1');
  var result = document.createTextNode('Your inputs are: ' + x);
  h1.appendChild(result);
  document.getElementById('results').appendChild(h1);
}
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: what does not work ? what error ?

Comment: Have you tried .forEach instead of a for loop?

Comment: @MichaelMishin The prompt box pops up six times in a row and then inputs are printed on the div element. I want each input print to happen after every prompt.

Comment: Do you want to print everything at once after six prompt?

Comment: @MichaelMishin No, I want print 1 to happen after prompt 1, print 2 to happen after prompt 2 till print 7 after prompt 7.

Comment: In this case your code should work

Comment: @MichaelMishin It will block in some browsers, like Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prompt and alert are blocking.

Give the interface time to update the DOM

Try this instead:

```js
let cnt = 7;
const addNum = () => {
  let x = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number"));
  h1 = document.createElement('h1');
  let result = document.createTextNode('Your inputs are: ' + x);
  h1.appendChild(result);
  document.getElementById('results').appendChild(h1);
  cnt--;
  if (cnt > 0) setTimeout(addNum,100);
};
addNum();
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```